# Ubuntu - Auto Pilot Open stack Deployment Guide

Tags: maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have Ubuntu 14.04.4 Installed and wondering if there is a guide step by step with details and screenshots to deploy the components below
MAAS-Landscape-OpenStack

The guide available online is not very helpful. In some cases apt-get not even working...

Comment: Well, I agree, not much documentation exists... However, Autopilot deploys openstack for you from the GUI.  So you don't see the inner working but that's somewhat the point.  You can skip using autopilot and simply follow one of the openstack ubuntu install guides.  If apt-get is failing, I would post another question with logging to try to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official guide.  If you have issues, please post a new question here with specifically what went wrong.

[Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot)

Comment: I am unable to Step 5 - Register your Hardware with MAAS......I did follow all previous steps per guide......Tried to reboot a machine that i would like to MAAS to display under nodes but nothing happens and the new Machine Node (although setup for PXE boot) times out...Also i am not seeing Network tab in MAAS GUI but instead there is Subnets.....Thank you

Comment: Do we absolutely need to install  and configure juju as part of the Openstack Autopilot ....Per step 2  we did sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable   but they were never installed.....Thank you

Comment: If PXE is timing out, you have an issue with your networking.

Answer (score 0):

You may definitely install OpenStack the hard way as you inquire, the steps are detailed in the official OpenStack install guides -- here is the link to the 14.04 "Liberty" version:

[Installing "Liberty" on Ubuntu 14.04](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/)

As you will quickly see, the details imply a lot more work that the Autopilot automates needs to be performed by the admin. If that's suitable, those are the docs!